# Conversión de un arreglo string a un arreglo int en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

He estado intentando hacer un programa en el cual, yo agregue datos de números pero en textos, que estos se agreguen a una listbox y posteriormente hacer la suma de dichos valores, solo que me han explicado que una vez de haber agregado los datos, ahora debo hacer un ciclo for para recorrer cada dato del primer arreglo y así poder convertir cada uno de ellos a un valor numérico.
Solo que al hacer la conversión en el botón de sumar, me dice que no tiene el formato correcto.
Muchas gracias!
el arreglo lo declaré en el public partial class de esta manera : string[] arreglo;

```
    private void bt_capturar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string datos = txb_numeros.Text;
        arreglo = datos.Split(',');
        lbx_elementos.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string elementos in arreglo)
        {
            lbx_elementos.Items.Add(elementos);
        }

    }

    private void bt_sumar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int suma = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < arreglo.Length; x++)
        {
            int numero;
            numero = int.Parse(arreglo[x]);
            suma = suma + numero;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("La suma es igual a " + suma.ToString());
    }
}
```

Buen día, muchísimas gracias a todos por sus respuestas, trataré de poner una imagen de la forma:)
[image: !]

Comment: tu código no se ve mal, estás seguro que ***todo lo que guardas en string, puede convertirse a número***?

Comment: ¿Asumo que quieres decir que `string[] arreglo` no `string[] array`? ¿Qué es exactamente lo que sale mal? `int.Parse` podría fallar cuando la cadena no es un entero adecuado (como `"string"`o incluso `"13.2"`)

Comment: Una pregunta tu escribes "uno", "dos", "tres" en vez de 1, 2, 3, es decir tu escribes el número con palabras?

Comment: Así es, es que creo que debo primero escribir la palabra y que esa palabra digamos "uno" se vaya guardando como 1, el número

Comment: Es que crees?, no estas seguro?, deberias aclararte primero

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la situacion esta en que no estas asegurando si el `string` solo contiene numero para ser convertidos a `int`. Intenta utilizando el metodo [`int.TryParse`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0) que te retorna true/false si es valido o no y te retorna la referencia del valor en caso de ser true:

```
private void bt_sumar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int suma = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < arreglo.Length; x++)
    {
        int numero = 0;
        
        // comprobamos si la cadena solo tiene numeros. 
        // Si es asi, la variable `numero` tendra el valor
        if(int.TryParse(arreglo[x], out numero) 
           suma = suma + numero;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("La suma es igual a " + suma.ToString());
}
```

---

Tambien otras formas de convetirlo a `int` y con menos codigo utilizando `Enumerable.Select`:

```
private void bt_sumar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int suma = arreglo.Select(int.Parse).Sum();    
    MessageBox.Show("La suma es igual a " + suma.ToString());
}
```

Pero si el `string` tiene un caracter lanzaria el mismo error por lo que entonces utilizamos `int.TryParse` en el cuerpo de la funcion:

```
private void bt_sumar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int suma = arreglo.Select(x=> {
        int numero = 0;
        
        if(int.TryParse(x, out numero))
            return numero;
        
        return 0;
    }).Sum();

    MessageBox.Show("La suma es igual a " + suma.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Hola! No sé muy bien como usar aún la página, pero me ha ayudado mucho las recomendaciones de todos, de verdad muchísimas gracias, llevaba días con el mismo programa:( utilicé esta solución que me dieron 'if(int.TryParse(arreglo[x], out numero)' solo que ahora cuando oprimo el botón de sumar me dice que la suma es igual a cero :0

Comment: Probablemente porque los `string`s contienen algun caracter no nulos? Puedes mostrar los valores que estan intentando convertir a `int`?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido correctamente hasta ahora es, ¿desea validar la entrada o convertirla en `bt_capturar_Click`?

En ese caso, puede hacer lo siguiente:

```
private void bt_capturar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string datos = txb_numeros.Text;
        arreglo = datos
          .Split(',')
          .Select(Int32.Parse)
          .ToArray();

        // O ignore los valores inválidos::
        //arreglo = datos
        //  .Split(',')
        //  .Select(s => Int32.TryParse(s, out int n) ? n : (int?)null)
        //  .Where(n => n != null)
        //  .ToArray();
        
        lbx_elementos.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string elementos in arreglo)
        {
            lbx_elementos.Items.Add(elementos.ToString()); // Maybe use AddRange?
        }

    }

    private void bt_sumar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("La suma es igual a " + arreglo.Sum());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución es la siguiente:

```
    private void bt_sumar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string datos = txb_numeros.Text;
        var arreglo = datos.Split(',');

        int suma = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < arreglo.Length; x++)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(arreglo[x], out int numero)){
                suma += numero;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("La suma es igual a " + suma.ToString());
    }
```

La variable arreglo debe existir en el contexto o bien volver a tomar los números.
Según el caso te recomiendo utilizar Trim() para quitar espacios o cosas que pudieran afectar a que los datos luego del split no sean enteros válidos.